IBM Liberty: Unable to create MQ session on application startup
I am trying to migrate one application from ibm webshpere 8.5 to IBM liberty server 24.
The app connects to IBM MQ to send and receive data. The application is not able to send data to mq for the first after application startup and fails with error

com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: MQJCA1020: The session is closed.
at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:189) ~[com.ibm.mq.connector.jar:?]
at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:111) ~[com.ibm.mq.connector.jar:?]
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.SessionWrapper.assertOpen(SessionWrapper.java:939) ~[com.ibm.mq.connector.jar:?]
at com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.SessionWrapper.createObjectMessage(SessionWrapper.java:210) ~[com.ibm.mq.connector.jar:?]

This fails only once after app starts and work correctly from second time onwards.
we have checked connectivity and everthing and it looks fine
server.xml
    <featureManager>
        <!--The following features are available in all editions of Liberty.-->
        <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
        <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jmsMdb-3.2</feature>
    </featureManager>
    <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>
    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="-1" httpsPort="${httpsPort}" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>
    <httpSession cookieName="${cookiename}" cookiePath="${cookiepath}" securityIntegrationEnabled="false"
                 cookieHttpOnly="${cookiehttpOnly}" cookiesEnabled="${cookiesenabled}" cookieSecure="true"/>
    <enterpriseApplication id="" location="/location/EAR.ear"
                           name="EAR">
        <web-ext context-root="" id="EAR.ear_web-ext_" moduleName="app"/>
        
    </enterpriseApplication>
    <library id="mssqllib">
        <fileset dir="${JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}" includes="${JDBC_DRIVER_FNAME}"/>
    </library>
    <dataSource beginTranForResultSetScrollingAPIs="false" beginTranForVendorAPIs="false" id="MssqlDS"
                jndiName="${JndiName}" type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="mssqllib"/>
        <properties databaseName="${DbName}" portNumber="${DbPort}" serverName="${DbHost}"
                    useNTLMv2="true" user="${DbUser}"
                    password="${DbPasswd}"/>
        <connectionManager connectionTimeout="180" maxPoolSize="10"/>
    </dataSource>
    <transaction heuristicRetryWait="0" propogatedOrBMTTranLifetimeTimeout="300"/>
    <jmsActivationSpec id="jms/MQActSpec" maxSequentialFailureCount="10">
        <properties.mqJmsRa brokerCCDurSubQueue="SYSTEM.JMS.D.CC.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE"
                            brokerCCSubQueue="SYSTEM.JMS.ND.CC.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE"
                            brokerControlQueue="SYSTEM.BROKER.CONTROL.QUEUE"
                            brokerSubQueue="SYSTEM.JMS.ND.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE" brokerVersion="1"
                            channel="${MQCHNL}" cleanupInterval="3600000"
                            destination-ref="jms/MQQ" destination="jms/MQQ"
                            hostName="${MQHOST}"
                            maxPoolDepth="20" messageRetention="YES" poolTimeout="300000"
                            port="${MQPORT}" sparseSubscriptions="FALSE"
                            maxSequentialFailureCount="10"
                            subscriptionDurability="Nondurable" subscriptionStore="MIGRATE" useJNDI="true"/>
    </jmsActivationSpec>
    <jmsQueueConnectionFactory id="jms/MQQCF"
                               jndiName="jms/MQQCF">
        <properties.mqJmsRa
                channel="${MQCHNL}"
                hostName="${MQHOST}"
                port="${MQPORT}"
                temporaryModel="SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE"/>
        <connectionManager connectionTimeout="180" maxPoolSize="20" minPoolSize="1"/>
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>
    <jmsQueue id="jms/MQQ" jndiName="jms/MQQ">
        <properties.mqJmsRa baseQueueName="${MQQ}"
                            receiveCCSID="1208" receiveConversion="QMGR"/>
    </jmsQueue>
    <ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore" trustStoreRef="defaultTrustStore"
         clientAuthenticationSupported="true" clientKeyAlias="${clientalias}" sslProtocol="${sslProtocol}"/>
    <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="/location/sslconf.jks" type="JKS"
              password="${jkspassword}"/>
    <keyStore id="defaultTrustStore" location="/location/sslconf.jks"
  

    
        <resourceAdapter id="mqJmsRa" location="${MQlibpath}/wmq.jmsra.rar">
            <classloader apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, api, third-party"/>
        </resourceAdapter>
        <variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="${MQlibpath}/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
    </server>```


wmq.jmsra.rar version is 9.2.0

I do not know if this would be relevant, but the element name given your example config should be properties.wmqJms not properties.mqJmsRa.  Given the error message I think I'd want to understand what the code is doing that catches this exception, but no code has been provided.

we tried with properties.wmqJms but we ge the same issue.
the code is very simple it does context.lookup on the jndi and create connection... we even removed the code where connection and sessions are getting close just to check this issue .. but we still got the error

@tepaja Please can you provide the code and some additional context with respect to the migration.
